# ArcGIS Esri feature layer query get object lat and long

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to do a query on a feature Layer and the get an object's Lat and Lng, so I can center it on the map. However after doing the query, I get a graphic that has only an x,y position. the extent.center.lat/long is null

Here is the code:

```
    centerAndZoomOnAsset(Id: string) {
    let query = this.pipeFL.createQuery();
    query.where = `Id = '${Id}'`;
    query.outFields = ['*'];
    this.pipeFL.queryFeatures(query).then((result: esri.FeatureSet) => {
      debugger;
      const foundFeatureGraphic: esri.Graphic = result.features[0];
      if (foundFeatureGraphic) {
        const center = foundFeatureGraphic.geometry.extent.center.clone();
        //this.mapView.goTo(foundFeatureGraphic);
        this.mapView.goTo({target: center});
      }
    });
  }
```

`center.latitude` and `center.longitude` are both `null`.

Comment: What is the coordinate system of your data?

Comment: Have you tried setting `query.returnGeometry = true;`?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue, I needed to tell the query what the spatial reference was.
I also added Berend's return Geometry too.

```
query.outSpatialReference = this.mapView.spatialReference;
query.returnGeometry = true;
```